Movie where only a man and a woman left astray in a random place, followed by big cloud of darkness
There is this one movie where the beginning is in an old farm side I think. 
Then after that, everything changes and a series of events occur. Then there is this girl inside a bus writing on her diary, and a guy met her. Then he was asking her questions like is she married or not and she giggles to him. Then he asked another question and right before she was about to answer, the bus crashes. Then they are later left astray in a random place. They both try to look around for mode; in front of them is just a whole, big cloud of darkness engulfing the whole space behind and then the girl realised that the darkness is actually moving towards them and they drove off. 
I saw this movie  a few months ago (think it should be around 2010s?) It is a western country I guess.
I wanted to continue watching it but I could not remember what the movie's name was. I am new here and hope to receive some good response.

Sounds like After from 2012. From an online review:

Ana and Freddy are strangers on a bus, when, by sheer coincidence, they start talking and discover that they actually live on the same road. With a sound of a crash and screeching tyres, Ana suddenly wakes up in bed. She is confused to find that she is alone in the town – she goes to work but no one is there, she peers in everybody’s windows but still nothing. But later that night she discovers that there is in fact someone else around, Freddy from the bus. Relieved to have encountered each other, they are then both alarmed at the sight of a huge black fog closing in on the town, getting closer and closer with each passing second.

He also flirts with her on the bus in the beginning and asks if she's married. Here's the trailer:




kinda reminds me of "Stranger Things" from netflix. the whole thing about the "shadow dimension"
